# Distribution of turbulent energy dissipation in a stirred tank

Tags: chemical-engineering, turbulence

Is detailed experimental information on the distribution of energy dissipation in a stirred tank(45o Pitch blade) available? I require this variation in all directions in a standard stirred tank configuration.